# mysql replace into alternative

Tags: mysql, replace

i'm currently using a replace into statement, I have a unique field which will cause it to UPDATE rather than INSERT if it finds a duplicate...

Problem is if it finds a duplicate i can't get to update on a few columns, it just wipes the lot.

Is there a similar "one statement" method where I can just UPDATE what I want?

I've found merge into but don't undertsnad the first bit about merge into table using table

Answer (score 16):

You're going to want to use the INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Here's an example that will try to create a record with an id, birthday, and name. If a record with the id field exists, it will do the update specified. The table has lots of other fields like email address, zip code, etc. I want to leave those fields alone if I update. (REPLACE INTO would lose any of that data if I didn't include it in the REPLACE INTO statement.)

```
INSERT INTO user (userid,birthday,first_name,last_name) 
   VALUES (1234,'1980-03-07','Joe','Smith') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
   birthday = '1980-03-07',
   first_name = 'Joe', 
   last_name = 'Smith';
```

Comment: Yeah, the disadvantage though is it takes a lot of writing.

Comment: There's also potentially a pretty hefty performance benefit from using INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/replace-into-think-twice. I'd say that's worth an additional minute of code writing...

Comment: @Alex Mather: you can also replace  birthday = '1980-03-07' with brithday = values(birthday) and the same for the remain columns.

Comment: @Jim Smith -- If you've found your answer please accept it. People will be more likely to answer your questions in the future.