# INSERT into sql database

Tags: php, sql

I've inserted into databases before but never used the 'where' feature. For some reason, it is not inserting, but dieing instead.

```
<?php
$member=$_SESSION['member'];

 $SQL = "INSERT into members where name='$member'(money) VALUES ('100')"; 
      mysql_query($SQL) or die("Could not insert money");

      print "Money successfully inserted";
?>
```

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do - a WHERE suggests you want to do an update. Either way you're probably best off looking at some tutorials.

Comment: Why do you have `(money)`... What did you intend...??

Comment: I guess you can find your answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948554/mysql-direct-insert-into-with-where-clause) : you can't Next time please use your favorite browser doing a quick search (it takes me about 30s)...

Comment: I am trying to insert 100 into the row 'money' where name='$member '@tramp

Comment: he is messing up a normal `INSERT INTO members (field) VALUES (value) ` method :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid SQL:

```
INSERT into members where name='$member'(money) VALUES ('100')
```

I would assume something like this:

```
update `members` set `money`=100 where `name`='$member';
```

---

Rationale: (money) is a field and 100 is the value for money (since those 2 make the most sense from a INSERT INTO members (field) VALUES (value) syntax point of view).

Answer (score 3):

Never die() with a fixed error message, especially when you can output the actual reason: `... or die(mysql_error())`.

But yes, your problem is a syntax error. `INSERT` queries do **NOT** have a `WHERE` clause - `where` is used to filter records already in the database table. This makes no sense for a new record, because it's not IN the table to filtered in the first place.

You query should basically be just

```
INSERT into members (name, money) VALUES ('$member', '100')
```

And note that you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are using a deprecated/obsolete database interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change existing data, use the update command instead of insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use WHERE clause with INSERT command

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html

You have to do an update

```
<?php
$member=$_SESSION['member'];

 $SQL = "UPDATE `members` SET `money`='100' WHERE `name`='$member'; "; 
      mysql_query($SQL) or die("Could not insert money");

      print "Money successfully inserted";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For inserting :

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO members(money) VALUES ('100')";
```

MySQL INSERT Syntax does not support the WHERE clause. [MySQL.com Insert Info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Are you actually trying to insert a new row, or update an existing 'member'? If update, then try:

```
UPDATE members SET money = 100, WHERE name='$member';
```